# How to/Should I unit test EventBus events with Mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I use Otto's EventBus in my Android app.

In my `LoginNetworkOperation` class, I catch different kinds of network connection errors and I post different bus events for each one, and my `LoginPresenter` class is registered as a listener and certain methods are invoked, when these events are fired.

My question is how (and should I) do I unit test whether the `LoginNetworkOperation` throws this event and `LoginPresenter` handles it with `Mockito`?

I looked at this question: [Guava EventBus unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414912/guava-eventbus-unit-tests) but it doesn't provide enough information, especially on the implementation part.

```
public class LoginNetworkOperation {

    public void execute(String username, String password) {
        try {
            // retrofit attempt
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bus.post(new ExceptionEvent(e));
        }
    }
}

public class LoginPresenter {

    void onExceptionEvent(ExceptionEvent exceptionEvent) {
        // Do Something with the exception event
    }
}
```

Also, which should be the `Subject Under Test` here and which should be the mocked object?

I am using JUnit + Mockito + Robolectric in Android Studio and my test artifact is Unit Tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is how (and should I) do I unit test whether the
>   LoginNetworkOperation throws this event and LoginPresenter handles it
>   with Mockito?

That's already an integration test: you're combining individual software modules and verifying their behaviour as a group.

In that case the "subject under test" is the combination of `LoginNetworkOperation`, `EventBus` and `LoginPresenter` and the mocked objects are the inputs to `LoginNetworkOperation` and whatever handles the output of `LoginPresenter`.

---

Those three software modules can also be unit tested:

- `LoginNetworkOperation.execute`: mock the `EventBus` and verify that it's called with the correct `ExceptionEvent` for different inputs.
- `LoginPresenter.onExceptionEvent`: verify correct behaviour for different `ExceptionEvents`.
- `EventBus.post`: register a mocked `ExceptionEvent`-Handler, post an `ExceptionEvent` and check that the Handler is called.

Comment: so I can register a Mock to listen for event bus events and make the EventBus post an event, and the mock is supposed to receive it?

Comment: in which of the tests i mentioned, the `EventBus.post` unit test? If so, yes.

Comment: But what about this recommendation of not mocking the classes we don't own? EventBus is a 3rd party library, so mocking it goes kinda against that unwritten law.